# Webclient send POST without body will get IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to make a POST call to an api through `WebClient` without a request body (the api does not need a body):

```
webClient.post()
         .uri("url")
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToMono(CustomResponse.class);
```

But the call returns an exception:

> The underlying HTTP client completed without emitting a
>   response.java.lang.IllegalStateException: The underlying HTTP client
>   completed without emitting a response.

For another API which requires a request body, I can successfully make a POST call with no issue:

```
webClient.post()
         .uri("url")
         .bodyValue("value")
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToMono(CustomResponse.class);
```

Is the problem related to the WebClient’s request body? How do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

The error happens because I added a `ContentType` header for Webclient through `.defaultHeader("ContentType", JSON)`.
The problem has gone after I've removed the header.

Comment: try using the `Void.class` or just to a `.then()` call after retrieve

Comment: I need to map the response body to the response model.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the downstream webservice responding too slow and exceeding connection timeout hence you're getting this issue.

In case you don't need (or response doesn't have body) you can use `.toBodilessEntity()` instead. So you code snippet can be rewritten:

```
webClient.post()
         .uri("url")
         .retrieve()
         .toBodilessEntity();
```

Why should you use it? Because you're always responsible for resources release. Please, read [NOTE section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#exchange--).

> When using **exchange()**, it is the responsibility of the application to
>   consume any response content regardless of the scenario (success,
>   error, unexpected data, etc). Not doing so can cause a memory leak.
>   See **ClientResponse** for a list of all the available options for
>   consuming the body.

Comment: I do need the response body, I think the problem is the request nody. I didn’t use ‘exchange’, I’m using ‘retrieve’.

Comment: @LunaticJape, sorry, my bad. Then it's probably because the external service response time takes more then your connection timeout

Comment: I’m using default setting, and I can get the response of other api using POST with a request body, like I mentioned in the second example.

Comment: You're getting response from **another** API. But what if you call your original API (that one where you have an issue) using **curl**, are you getting a response in that case or it's freezing?

Comment: I haven't tried curl, but I tried postman, I can get the response from Postman. Just FYI, the exception returns immediately after the call, it seems that t does not even have waiting/processing time.

Comment: I have no ideas then, sorry. I've created a minimal project when I'm doing the same thing and I was able to call external service with POST method without providing any body. If you wish, I can share a link to my repository.

Comment: Turns out that I've added a `ContentType` default header for my webclient.